# Two column padding and title

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble to fix my css: 
I am using bootstrap 4 and I have a row with two col with inside two charts
it looks like the following:

[image]

I have added some padding-left and right to create a space between the two col but now when I add a title it does not recover all the div 
How can I make it look like a real title ? 
[image]

here is my code :

```css
.graph-info,
.motivation-info {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.action-info,
.behaviour-info {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.radar-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.classWithPad {
  border: 1px solid rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.3);
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.05);
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.radar-container .row {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.classWithPad h2 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #292B2C;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container radar-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col graph-info">
      <div class="col classWithPad">
        <h2>title</h2>
        <canvas id="info_process"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col action-info">
      <div class="col classWithPad">
        <h2>title</h2>
        <canvas id="info_process2"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Reducing the h2's top margin springs to mind... margins can be negative. How about giving it a relative position or a translation. By the way, your screenshots don't match your code.

Comment: Do you want one title for both columns insted of two titels for each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Bootstrap Card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) to solve this:

```css
/** only to show some content */
#info_process {
  background:url('https://placehold.it/100x100');
  width:100%;
}
#info_process2 {
  background:url('https://placehold.it/100x100');
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-6">
      <div class="card">
        <h2 class="card-header text-center bg-dark text-white">title</h2>
        <div class="card-body">
          <canvas id="info_process"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-6">
      <div class="card">
        <h2 class="card-header text-center bg-dark text-white">title</h2>
        <div class="card-body">
          <canvas id="info_process2"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Example Canvas Center Div</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
  .graph-info,
  .motivation-info {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }

  .action-info,
  .behaviour-info {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }



  .radar-container {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }

  .classWithPad {
    border: 1px solid rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.3);
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.05);
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .radar-container .row {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  
  .classWithPad {
    border: 1px solid rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.3);
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(102, 187, 158, 0.05);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

  .classWithPad h2 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #292B2C;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  }

  canvas {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="container radar-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col graph-info">
        <div class="col classWithPad">
          <h2>title</h2>
          
            <canvas id="info_process" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
              Your Canvas
              </canvas>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col action-info">
        <div class="col classWithPad">
          <h2>title</h2>
       
            <canvas id="info_process2" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
              Your Canvas
            </canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```